# Regex to replace cash values in a string

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to make a regex to replace cash values in a sentence, and so far I am using this regex `[+-]?\$\s?((\d{1,3},?)+.?\d{2}?)\b`.

Here are the test cases I came up with where `test` are cases that should be captured and replaced and `ntest` are fals positives.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string test = "$500, $5,000.00  $50.00   $.99  $80 -$500 $90!";
    string output = Regex.Replace(test, @"[+-]?\$\s?((\d{1,3},?)+.?\d{2}?)\b", "money");
    Console.WriteLine(output);

    string ntest = "a$500, 00$5,000.00  $50.$00   $.99.00.00  $80.0000 --$90.00  !$90 ";
    string output2 = Regex.Replace(ntest, @"[+-]?\$\s?((\d{1,3},?)+.?\d{2}?)\b", "money");
    Console.WriteLine(output2);

}
```

So far it captures most of the test cases, but I am having trouble defining the boundaries. Results:

```
money, money  money   $.99  $80 money $90!
amoneymoney  $50.$00   $.99.00.00  $80.0000 -money  !$90
```

The results should actually look like:

```
money, money  money   money  money money money!
a$500, 00$5,000.00  $50.$00   $.99.00.00  $80.0000 --$90.00  !$90
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this regex:

```
(?<=\s|^)\B[+-]?\$\s?\d{0,3}(?:,?\d{3})*(?:\.?\d{2})?\b(?=(?!\.)\p{P}|\s|$)
```

(Or, equivalent: `(?<=\s|^)\B[+-]?\$\s?\d{0,3}(?:,?\d{3})*(?:\.?\d{2})?\b(?=[\p{P}-[.]]|\s|$)`)

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5cs%7c%5e)%5cB%5b%2b-%5d%3f%5c%24%5cs%3f%5cd%7b0%2c3%7d(%3f%3a%2c%3f%5cd%7b3%7d)*(%3f%3a%5c.%3f%5cd%7b2%7d)%3f%5cb(%3f%3d(%3f!%5c.)%5cp%7bP%7d%7c%5cs%7c%24)&i=%24500%2c+%245%2c000.00++%2450.00+++%24.99++%2480+-%24500+%2490!+%24+568%2c888++%241000000+and+%24100000.00%0d%0aa%24500%2c+00%245%2c000.00++%2450.%2400+++%24.99.00.00++%2480.0000+--%2490.00++!%2490+&r=money)

[image]

Comment: close but you captured the comma and exclamation

Comment: I forgot two more cases $1000000 and $100000.00

Comment: Just made the comma optional.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are exactly looking for, but you can try something like this:

```
(?<=\s|\A)\B[+-]?\$\d{0,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{2})?\b(?=\s|\p{P}(?![\d$])|\z)
```